# Is this the right mounting screws of my Dell Inspiron 531S?

Tags: hard-drive, mount, dell-inspiron

I'm refurbishing a 2008 era Dell Inspiron 531S. It did not come with a hard drive, so I have had to guess at the correct screws to get one to mount. The mechanism uses the screws themselves as sleds, which lock the drive into place with a small plastic clasp.

The issue I'm having is that the force is very loose when locked in place, as if there should be a thicker screw or some kind of rubber grommet on it.

Is this the correct way to mount a drive to this computer?

I made a video to demonstrate how much play there is after mounting the drive. I can't imagine that this amount of play is correct for a hard drive.

https://youtu.be/NhZ03Pkg6AM?si=Z6MaEJ1GqpZklc1u

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Those look correctish to me but let it be known. It doesn't matter.  Those actually look like case screws which have a different gauge.  A piece of duct tape or even nothing at all if the pc doesn't  move will do the trick.  Screw them into the hard drive by hand and see if the screws fit.  If they do! USE EM!  Half of my machines (many are YEARS OLD) don't even have the drives actually mounted.  It doesn't matter, they won't move unless you move them.  30+ years exp.

Comment: those look like the correct screws